# undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "":String when using meta_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my _search_box.html.erb file

```
<%= form_tag "/catalog/search", :method => "get" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q %> 
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

which is rendered in `search.html.erb`:

```
<%= render :partial => 'search_box' %>
<% if @products %>
    <%= render(:partial => "products") %>
<% end %>
```

And this is my `search` method for the `CatalogController` class:

```
  def search
    @search = Product.search(params[:q].to_s)
    @products = @search.all
    unless @products.size > 0
      flash.now[:notice] = "No results."
    end
  end
```

I get this error when I access `/catalog/search`

```
NoMethodError in CatalogController#search

undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "":String
```

I am using `meta_search` gem for the search.

What is happening?

Comment: what value does `params[:q]` holds?

Comment: whatever is input in the textfield

Comment: You already have your answer in the link which @GraemeMcLean attached.

Comment: I get undefined method `controller=' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::Product:0x007f70d451c560>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be putting the value of what you want to search for directly into `q`.  `q` is supposed to be a hash of all your search conditions.  For example:

```
q: { name_contains: 'something interesting', price_less_than: '100' }
```

Like this the search conditions come into the controller in `params[:q]`.  If you don't want to use this hash and have just a single search field for the product's name say, then change your view to be something like this if you want to do a substring match:

```
<%= text_field_tag :name_contains %>
```

or this, if you want to do an exact match:

```
<%= text_field_tag :name_equals %>
```

and change your controller search method to be:

```
def search
  @search = Product.search params
  ...
```

However, if you use this approach then be careful you never have any non-search related parameters coming in otherwise they will go to MetaSearch too, which is why normally you should use the `q` hash.

Finally, the MetaSearch gem is quite old and no longer maintained now.  If you are just starting with setting up searching, maybe take a look at [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) instead which in its simple mode is basically a rewrite of MetaSearch.

Comment: if I wanted to search by different values, how should I do it?

Comment: I am using your answer and I get no results for a search.

Comment: products whose names match the input

Comment: I've edited my answer to use a field called `name` instead of `product_name`.  I realise that since you are searching on the product table, it might have looked like the construct was `<table>_<field>_<where>`.  Actually it is just `<field>_<where>`.